# Creating a Windows Mobile Database Application Using .NET and SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, windows-mobile

Im doing a project of order management system and the scenario is like this

Medical Representative goes to a pharmaceutical company and delivers all the orders required by him.After the completion of the delivery,Medical Representative have to take printout of the bill using his windows mobile phone.Is this possible ????

If possible what all things should be installed on the phone ??

Can we install sqlserver on mobile device like we do in pc ??

Can we take printout from a mobile device if we have a portable printer via bluetooth ?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a smart device project using Visual studio 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5, then SQL Server Compact 3.5 will be automatically installed on your mobile device when you deploy the application.

These links will be useful to you towards that end

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsmobile/bb264318

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb278115.aspx

As for printing, I think that can be done as well.